# Possible remainders from modular conditional

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

**I have this question:**

[image]

**By writing code and testing all outputs between `1` and `10**6`, I got the probabilites for the 7 different outputs. How can I solve this question mathematically?** Thank you

Comment: I think there may be more than $7$ different outputs

Comment: Look at all numbers from $1$ to $30$, to see what they return (or run the function using your favourite language, if you prefer that). Write it down in a row. Then do $31$ to $60$, write it down in a new row below the old one. You should see a pattern. Then you could think of how to describe that pattern, and finally how to prove that it continues forever.

Comment: @Arthur thank you, why until 30, can you maybe provide an answer? That would be great

Comment: $30$ was not randomly picked, that is true. Think about what special thing happens in the function when you give it $30$ that doesn't happen to any smaller number.

Answer (score 1):

The condition in each of the three if statements can be true or false, and all combinations are possible, so there are $2^3=8$ possible outputs.

To output, for example, $6$, the first two must be true and the third false, i.e. $x$ must be divisible by $2$ and $3$ but not $5$. So how many of the numbers up to $10^6$ are multiples of $2$ and $3$ (i.e. multiples of $6$)? How many of those are also multiples of $5$? The difference is the number of possible $x$ which will give you that output.

Answer (score 1):

To start, let's work with inputs from $1$ to $30$ (which is the lcm of $2$, $3$ and $5$).

There are $8$ different outputs:

- $1$ for $x\in\{1,7,11,13,17,19,23,29\}$.
- $2$ for $x\in\{2,4,8,14,16,22,26,28\}$.
- $3$ for $x\in\{3,9,21,27\}$.
- $5$ for $x\in\{5,25\}$.
- $6$ for $x\in\{6,12,18,24\}$.
- $10$ for $x\in\{10,20\}$.
- $15$ for $x=15$.
- $30$ for $x=30$.

Note that the output is periodic with period $30$, that is, $f(x+30)=f(x)$. So we can easily extend this result to $10^6-10=30\times33333$.

The outputs for the last ten possible inputs are, in the same order: $1,2,3,2,5,6,1,2,3,10$.

So the number of times that the output is $1$ is $333333\times 8+2$, and the probability that the output is $1$ is 
$$\frac{33333\times 8+2}{10^6}$$

Can you finish?

Comment: Thank you so much, this answer is perfect! I'm only not sure where the 2 comes from. Can you explain that please? I guess for the output 2 the result is: (33333 * 8 + 2?)/ (10**6)

Comment: That $2$ comes from the *two* ones that occurs in the last ten numbers. Since there are *three* twos in the set of outputs of the last ten numbers, the probability for $2$ is $(33333\times8+3)/10^6$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**
Part $a)$ is answered nicely by @Especially Lime. For part $b)$, let's define $A_i$ as the set of numbers between given interval that is divisible by $i$. So we are interested in $A_2$, $A_3$ and $A_5$. As expained above/below, there are $8$ different outputs, namely $1,2,3,5,6,10,15,30$. And corresponding sets have sizes $(|\Omega|-|A_2 \cup A_3 \cup A_5|),|A_2|,|A_3|,|A_5|,|A_2 \cap A_3|,|A_2\cap A_5|,|A_3 \cap A_5|, |A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_5|$, where $\Omega = \{1,2,...,1000000\}$. Now with the help of Inclusion-Exclusion Principle, you can find all of these sizes and corresponding probabilities.

(For example, $|A_2 \cap A_3| = \lfloor\frac{1000000}{2\cdot 3}\rfloor$)

(Use Inclusion-Exclusion Principle to find $|\Omega|-|A_2 \cup A_3 \cup A_5|$)